# Windows 8 "devcon -remove" issue

Tags: windows-8, device-driver

Running Windows 8 with 2 video cards, AMD/ATI 6870 + 4870. Windows 8 is disabling 48XX card seemingly random and for no reason that I have been able to see in the event viewer. My work around is uninstall in devmgmt.msc and rescan for hardware changes. It auto installs and works fine after for days.

Question is how to automate that process with devcon. Trying...

```
C:\Batch>devcon.exe listclass display

Listing 2 device(s) for setup class "Display" (Display adapters).
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6738&SUBSYS_E177174B&REV_00\4&1DCBFDE5&0&0010: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.20)
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_9442&SUBSYS_E810174B&REV_00\4&24DEEBC4&0&0018: ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1)

C:\Batch>devcon.exe remove =display *HD 4800*

No devices removed.
```

Doesn't remove the adapter. Not sure what I am missing to get this to work. I don't work with devcon very much and just wanted to make a batch to speed this "fix".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use adapter name as an id for `devcon`.

Use, for example, device id: `devcon.exe remove =display *DEV_9442*`.